# How do I fix the misshape in a CNN?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, convolution

I wrote a simple CNN with a maxpool, a dense layer and a drop layer. Unfortunately there is two messages why it doesn't work. 
In a normal session codes complaines about a misshape between y_conv and y_

```
nsorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1400] vs. [100]
 [[Node: eval/Equal = Equal[T=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](eval/ArgMax, eval/ArgMax_1)]]
```

If I use the invoke stepper from the tensorflow debugger I get the message "Attempting to use uniniatialized variables". I am very confused. Does anyone have a clue?

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name="entry")

#layer conv 1

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32], "Wconv1") # 5 x 5 
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32], "bconv1")

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)


#layer pool1
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
h_pool1 = tf.Print(h_pool1, [tf.shape(h_pool1)], 'shape=')

# Dense Layer

W_fc1 = weight_variable([ 7 * 64, 1024], "Wconv2") # 7 x 7 
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024], "bconv2")

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool1, [-1, 7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

#drop out

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout (h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10], "WconvD")
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10], "bconv2")

# softmax

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2, name="y_conv")


with tf.name_scope('train'):
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="y_")
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.name_scope('eval'):
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
```

These are the definitions of some functions:

```
def weight_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, name=name) #normalverteilung
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape, name):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape, name=name)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name="maxpool")
```

Comment: What are the `max_pool_2x2` and `conv2d` functions?  I'm guessing you're doing something inconsistent with the strides or the pool size.

Comment: Also, it may be easier to use `tf.layers` for this.

Comment: I add the definitions. For my use case (and studying) tf.layers doensnt help. 
In the end I feel it is the mentioned problem but I cant debug because of "attempting variabels error"

Comment: I think `W_fc1` should have a first dimension of 14*14*32 since after convolution with a stride of 1 and max pooling with a stride of 2 the image will be of size 14x14 and the number of channels will be 32.